# How do I separate parts from an object?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, edit-mode, sculpting, .fbx

I have downloaded an FBX object and now I want to separate the face parts so I can move each part of it.

[image]

Comment: that depends on the topology of that object, It doesn't seem to be loose, if it would you would separate by loose parts, This way as it is I can only see either selecting it part by part and separating or retopology of each piece

Comment: please provide blend file so we can help you